# HERE maps requests counting in android map

Tags: android, maps, here-api

Maybe someone have some expirience with this maps and tell me how can I interpret the HERE maps Api requests. I know that the free plan offer 15k request per month, but after one day development Ive got 1.7k requests (I only turn on my map and try to localize it self using PositioningManager). I dont know how they counting the requestes, maybe it is my implementation fault (I do some operation whenever `OnPositionChangedListener` is called) I want to add turn by turn navigation and want that about 100 users have fun in my app per one day but I scared that it can be even above that limit.

In the plan page they said that :

> What's a transaction? For most of our services, a transaction is one server request. For map, satellite and traffic tiles, it's 15 requests.

my report (that claims that 99.99% of requests are map tiles):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For map tiles, every 15 requests will be calculated as 1 transaction. Every time you are moving a screen, changing location or zoom in or out it loading new tiles.